# Disable redrawing canvas after screen resize and mobile rotation in PaperJS

Tags: javascript, paperjs

The use case is for a Christmas "scratch" card, where the user needs to swipe on the image to reveal the content. When the window is resized or the phone is rotated, the canvas is redrawn. My current code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Division Raster</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
// Based on 'JPEG Raster' by Jonathan Puckey:
// http://www.flickr.com/photos/puckey/3179779686/in/photostream/
// Create a raster item using the image with id='mona'
var raster = new Raster('mona');
// Make the raster invisible:
raster.visible = true;
raster.position = view.center;
var lastPos = view.center;

function moveHandler(event) {
    if (lastPos.getDistance(event.point) < 1)
        return;
    lastPos = event.point;
    var size = this.bounds.size.clone();
    var isLandscape = size.width > size.height;
    // If the path is in landscape orientation, we're going to
    // split the path horizontally, otherwise vertically:
    size /= isLandscape ? [2, 1] : [1, 2];
    if (size.ceil().width > 10) {
      var path = new Path.Rectangle({
          point: this.bounds.topLeft.floor(),
          size: size.ceil(),
          onMouseMove: moveHandler
      });
      path.fillColor = raster.getAverageColor(path);
      var path = new Path.Rectangle({
          point: isLandscape
              ? this.bounds.topCenter.ceil()
              : this.bounds.leftCenter.ceil(),
          size: size.floor(),
          onMouseMove: moveHandler
      });
      path.fillColor = raster.getAverageColor(path);
    }
    this.remove();
}

function onResize(event) {
    project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
    // Transform the raster so that it fills the bounding rectangle
    // of the view:
    raster.fitBounds(view.bounds, true);
    // Create a path that fills the view, and fill it with
    // the average color of the raster:
    new Path.Rectangle({
        rectangle: view.bounds,
        fillColor: raster.getAverageColor(view.bounds),
        onMouseMove: moveHandler
    });
}

    </script>
    <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">

            #canvas{
        background: center center url(/web.jpg);
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }

#cc{
    max-width:2560px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}       </style>
</head>
        <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
        <img width="1024" height="1024" id="mona" style="display: none;" src="/web.jpg">
      </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to fix the initial canvas size so the result of the "scratching" isn't lost?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem resides in the `onResize` function which is called every time the window is resized and which basically reset your drawing.
The `resize` attribute on the `<canvas>` element also is part of the problem as it makes sure that the canvas size is updated every time the window is resized.
In your case, I think that you want to get rid of those.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/6dvap40k/) adapted from your code, turning it into a static drawing that doesn't respond to resize events.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Division Raster</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        // Load image then init.
        var raster = new Raster({
            source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            onLoad: init
        });

        function init() {
            // Make image fill the whole canvas.
            raster.fitBounds(view.bounds, true);

            var lastPos = view.center;

            function moveHandler(event) {
                if (lastPos.getDistance(event.point) < 1) {
                    return;
                }
                lastPos = event.point;
                var size = this.bounds.size.clone();
                var isLandscape = size.width > size.height;
                // If the path is in landscape orientation, we're going to
                // split the path horizontally, otherwise vertically:
                size /= isLandscape ? [2, 1] : [1, 2];
                if (size.ceil().width > 10) {
                    var path = new Path.Rectangle({
                        point: this.bounds.topLeft.floor(),
                        size: size.ceil(),
                        onMouseMove: moveHandler
                    });
                    path.fillColor = raster.getAverageColor(path);
                    var path = new Path.Rectangle({
                        point: isLandscape
                            ? this.bounds.topCenter.ceil()
                            : this.bounds.leftCenter.ceil(),
                        size: size.floor(),
                        onMouseMove: moveHandler
                    });
                    path.fillColor = raster.getAverageColor(path);
                }
                this.remove();
            }

            // Create a path that fills the view, and fill it with
            // the average color of the raster:
            new Path.Rectangle({
                rectangle: view.bounds,
                fillColor: raster.getAverageColor(view.bounds),
                onMouseMove: moveHandler
            });
        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas {
            width    : 100vw;
            height   : 100vh;
            position : absolute;
            top      : 0;
            left     : 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```